# Get an object id from HTML in in request.POST

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an user with list of tasks that he can add. I want to give him ability to delete those tasks, or mark as done.

The problem is that my solution is working only when user has one task, because of non-unique id's problem

Is there any way to pass the id to html so that it will be easily accesible in views? Thank you!

This is my current code

```
{% for task in tasks %}
        <form id='is_checked' method='POST' action="{% url 'mark_as_done'%}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-group-text">
                <input type="hidden" id="id_checked" value="{{task.id}}" name = "id_checked">
            </div>
        </form>

        <form class="input-group" action="{% url 'delete_task'%}" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">
                    <input onChange="document.getElementById('is_checked').submit()" type="checkbox" {% if task.is_done %}checked{% endif %}>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h7 type="text" class="form-control">{{task}}</h7>
            <input type="hidden" id="id" value="{{task.id}}" name = "id">
            <button type="submit" class="input-group-append btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </form>


    {% endfor %}
```

And in views:

````
def delete_task(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task = Task.objects.get(pk=request.POST['id'])
        task.delete()
        return redirect('tasks')

@login_required()
def mark_as_done(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task = Task.objects.get(pk=request.POST['id_checked'])
        task.is_done = True
        task.save()
    return redirect('tasks')```
````

Comment: Exactly what do you mean wit non-unique ids? Normally the primary key of an object is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Do you want to get id after save new tasks?

Comment: you are creating multiple forms, that's not a proper way, use ajax and jquery to pass id and delete multi checked values

Comment: Yes, I want to get id after new task is saved. By non-unique id i mean html id. Sorry for not being specific, these are my first steps in django

Comment: the id of new task is ```task.id```